# Run python script with integer arguments & variables in Colab

Tags: python, arguments, google-colaboratory

In Colab, I set variables outside and I want to pass them to a python script I call. Normal methods with {VAR} or $VAR do not work. What I understand, as it opens a new shell to run it, all is passed as strings and the python script does not have any conversion utilities.

```
MYVAR=3

!python3 myscript.py --int-arg {MYVAR}
!python3 myscript.py --int-arg $MYVAR
```

The first version complains:

> error: argument --int_arg: invalid int value: '{MYVAR}'

The second version complains:

> error: argument --int_arg: expected one argument

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that Colab's implementation does not like capitals. The following works:

```
my_var=3

!python3 myscript.py --int-arg {my_var}
```